# What's the workaround for not being able to pass heap objects to a future method?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

This seriously is one of the biggest thorns in my side. SFDC does not allow you to use complex objects or collections of objects as parameters to a future call. What is the best workaround for this?

Currently what I have done is passed in multiple parallel arrays of primitives which form a complete object based on the index. Meaning if I need to pass a collections of users, I may pass 3 string arrays, say - Name[], Id[], and Role[]. Name[0], Id[0]. and Role[0] are the first user, etc. This means I have to build all these arrays and build the future method to reconstruct the relevant objects on the other end as well.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is this a rant or a question?

Comment: I'll admit it's a bit of both. If there is a better way to do this I would appreciate it. I'd like to learn what the best practice is in this regard as it's something I run in to from time to time.

Comment: I think the question is, "What's the workaround for not being able to pass heap objects to a future method?"

Comment: Ok I've edited the question and content to be less of a rant and used your question title Jeremy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to why, once an Apex "transaction" is complete, the VM is destroyed. And generally speaking, salesforce will not serialize your object graph for resuming at a future time.

There may be a better way to get this task done. Can the future method query for the objects it needs to act on? Perhaps you can pass the List of Ids and the future method can use this in a WHERE clause. If it's a large number of objects, batch apex may be useful to avoid governor limits.

Comment: I could see how that might work if using sObjects. My problem is probably compounded by doing callouts, often which need complex data that isn't necessarily stored in an sObject (it may be some custom class object). I'll keep this in mind when sObjects are involved though.

Comment: Can you make the outbound call from the future method? That's a common use case for futures.

Comment: The outbound call is being made from the future method - which is why I am trying to get these objects in the future method in the first place. Another thing I'm having to fight are governor limits so I have to be careful how I structure futures and callouts.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest creating a new custom object specifically for storing the information required in your custom apex class. You can then insert these into the database and then query for the records in the `@future` method before using them for the callout.

Then, once the callout has completed successfully you can then delete those records from the database to keep things nice and tidy.

Comment: This is definitely a possibility, it just seems like a lot of work - for the developer and the system - both in building the object in the system, creating it in code, saving it, querying for it, deleting it, etc. It's probably the least "hack" way to go about it though.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is essentially the same. What I do is prepare a custom queue object with all relevant Ids (User/Contact/Lead/etc.) along with my custom data that then gets handled from the @Future call. This helps with governor limits since you can pull from the queue only what your callout and future limitations will permit you to handle in a single thread. For Facebook, for example, you can batch up 20 profile updates per single callout. Each @Future allows 10 callouts and each thread permits 10 @Future calls which equals 2000 individual Facebook profile updates - IF you're handling your batches properly and IF you have enough Salesforce seats to permit this number of @Future calls. It's 200 @Future calls per user per 24 hours last I checked.

The road gets narrow when you're performing triggered callouts, which is what I assume you're trying to do based on your need to callout in an @Future method in the first place. If you're not in a trigger, then you may be able to handle your callouts as long as you do them before processing any DML. In other words, postpone any data saves in any particular thread until you're done calling out.

But since it sounds like you need to call out from a trigger, batching it up in sObjects is really the way to go. It's a bit of work, but essentially serializing your existing heap data is the road to travel here. Also consider doing this from an hourly scheduled Batch Apex call since with the queue approach you'll be able to process all of your callouts eventually. If you run into governor limits (or rather, avoid hitting them) in a particular thread, it will wake up an hour later and finish the work left in your queue. Launching that process looks something like this:

```
String jobId = System.schedule('YourScheduleName', '0 0 0-23 * * ?', new ScheduleableClass());
```

This will instantiate an instance of ScheduleableClass once an hour which would pull the work from your queue object and process the maximum amount of callouts.

Good luck and sorry for the frustration.

Comment: It will be interesting to see if they will change their throttling limits on things like futures and callouts, especially with the new push for the "social enterprise" and rising use of 3rd party APIs that will entail. The limits you mentioned are also things I've ran into before, and are a reason why I'm using futures in this case (to be able to do more than just 10 callouts at once). Updating over time is not always a very viable option, however.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to give my answer on how I do this very easily in case anyone else stumbles across this question. Apex has functions to easily serialize and de-serialize objects to and from JSON encoding. Let's say I have a list of cases that I need to do something with in a future call:

```
String jsonCaseList = '';
List<Case> caseList = [SELECT id, Other fields FROM Case WHERE some conditions];
//Populate the list

//Serialize your list
jsonCaseList = JSON.serialize(caseList);

//Pass jsonCaseList as a string parameter to your future call

futureCaseActivity(jsonCaseList);

@future
public static void futureCaseActivity(string jsonCases){

  //De-serialize the string back into a list of cases
  List<Case> futureCaseList = (List<Case>)JSON.deserialize(jsonCases, List<Case>);

  //Do whatever you want with your cases
  for(Case c : futureCaseList){
    //Stuff
  }

Update futureCaseList;
}
```

Anyway, seems like a much better option than adding database clutter with a new custom object and prevents needing to query the database again for info you already have, which just makes me hurt inside.

Almost forgot to add the link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_json.htm